# Печать html страницы с помощью QWebView (PyQt4). Не умещается вся страница

Tags: python, html, pyqt, pyqt4, xlsx

Есть программа, написанная на языке Python3, интерпретатор версии 3.7, используется фреймворк PyQt4. Она открывает html файлы и позволяет печатать их. Для отображения страниц используется класс QtWebKit.QWebView. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть и какая-то возможность распечатать страницу html целиком, если она слишком широкая и не помещается на вертикальном листе А4?
Вот как выглядит главное окно приложения:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, не вся страница умещается целиком. В результате печати последний столбец обрезается и не печатается на листе А4. Получается печать следующего вида: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код слота, который выполняется при нажатии на кнопку "Печать":

```
def print_dialog(view):
    """Open system printing dialog"""
    printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)
    dialog = QtGui.QPrintDialog(printer)
    if dialog.exec_() != QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
        return
    view.print_(printer)
```

Здесь view - объект класса QtWebKit.QWebView.